# Can you connect R to WAVE datasets?

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Given that Wave Analytics is used for looking at data  from passive perspective, is there a way to connect Wave data sets into R?  Or other statistical modelling tool?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options I can think of

1. Export the data out of wave datasets either using the [DataSet Utils](https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils) or the [Wave Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_rest.meta/bi_dev_guide_rest/) into a CSV file and then import that into your statistical tool...
2. Find connectors from one of the Wave compatible 3rd party integrators like Informatica / Mulesoft that can transfer data between Wave and R